# Python Tkinter OOP Layout Configuration

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, layout

I am trying to build an application with tkinter.
The layout works without OO principles, but I am struggling to understand how I should move it to OO.

The layout is as shown in the pic below. (1280x720px)
[image]

---

I have the following:

- banner on top with username/welcome message, and logo rh corner, columnspan=8
- menu bar with buttons on the left, split into 2 rows (row1: rowspan 6, row2: rowspan=4)
- working area (white block) that has a Frame, which I'll add a notebook to, each menu button opening a different notebook page.

What is the best way to make this OO? (I am still learning, so very new to OO)

Comment: If you are at the point where you want to change your code from process orientated to object orientated and you think there is a magic way of avoiding to write those codes new, you are wrong. My advice, leave your working exampel as it is. Just because it works. While learning OOP you can just *translate* the code by nearly copy and paste. It still needs some effort, but you wont get angry while you messed up your working exampel.

Comment: best way is to first really learn `OOP` and later translate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight translation possible, since everything depends on your needs.
If you create a simple programm you can just create the class and create every Button,Label,Frame... in the constructor. When created you have to choose one of the layout managers grid,pack or place. After that you create your functions and you are done. If you deal with bigger projects and have a big amount of Labels, Buttons etc.. you maybe want to create containers for each.
In your case you wont need a lot of functions and buttons, so you should maybe go with the basic approach:

```
from tkinter import *

class name_gui:
    def __init__(self, top):

#specify main window

        self.top = top
        self.title = top.title("name_gui")
        self.minsize = top.geometry("1280x720")
        self.resizable = top.resizable(height=False,width=False)

#create buttons,Labels,Frames..

        self.Button1 = Button(top,text="Button1",command=self.exa_fun)
        self.Button2 = Button(top,text="Button2",command=self.exa_fun2)

#place them, choose grid/place/pack

        self.Button1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5)
        self.Button2.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.2)


#create your functions
    
    def exa_fun(self):
        pass

    def exa_fun2(self):
        pass


top = Tk()
exa_gui = name_gui(top)
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, with my attempts I made a mistake somewhere that kept opening a double window.
This worked well. Appreciate it

Comment: you are welcome. here should be everything you need: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html